# How could I access a variable from a class with a method from another class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Hi my english is not very good, so i'll try my best to explain my problem
I'm new with cocoa and xcode so maybe my problem is easier than i think

I have class , that's basically is a formulary for register client information, there i defined a method - (void)searcht:(NSString*)s; this method make a query to the database where the code = s

```
- (void) searcht:(NSString *)s{
    PGSQLConnection *connection1= [[PGSQLConnection alloc] init];
NSString *cmd=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from oc_master_customer where customer_id=%@",s  ];
    NSLog(@"%@", cmd);


    if ([connection1 connect]){
        NSLog(@" ENTRO  %@", [connection1 lastError]);
                PGSQLRecordset *rs1 = [connection1 open:cmd];
        if (![rs1 isEOF])
        {
            NSLog(@" ENTRO  2 %@", [connection1 lastError]);
            [matchcode setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"matchcode"] asString]];
            NSLog(@" MATCHCODE %@", [matchcode stringValue]);
            NSLog(@" MATCHCODE 2 %@", [[rs1 fieldByName:@"matchcode"] asString]);
            [name1 setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"name1"] asString]];
            [zip setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"zip"] asString]];
            [bank_code setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"bank_code"] asString]];
            [bank_account setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"bank_account"] asString]];
            [bank_name setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"bank_name"] asString]];
            [bank_iban setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"bank_iban"] asString]];
            [bank_swift setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"bank_swift"] asString]];
            [city setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"city"] asString]];
            [city_part setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"citypart"] asString]];
            [street setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"street"] asString]];
            [country setStringValue:
             [[rs1 fieldByName:@"country_code"] asString]];
        }

        [connection1 close];
        [rs1 close];}
}
```

I use this method with a NSSearchfield and it worked perfectly, now i made a subclass of nsearchfield and i want to call this method when the user pressed enter, i could access to the method  but i can't change the string values from the IBOutlets. I already have declared the IBOutlets as @public. My code from the nssearchfiel subclass

```
-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event
    {
        if ([event keyCode]==36){
        [[self window] selectKeyViewFollowingView:self];
        customers* c= [[customers alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"Key released: %@",[self stringValue]);
        [c searcht:[self stringValue]];
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the method i defined doesn't do a thing if i called from other class
 somebody have an idea of that what i have to do or i missing

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reformat your code to make it more readable. Also, I don't quite understand the problem you're having. Could you please point out what in your sample code is not working properly? To be specific, can you remove the code that's working, to make it clearer what's not?

Comment: my code works aat but, when i called the method that i defined in customers.m from my subclass searchfield.m it can't change the string values from the IBoutlets defined in customers.h so i guess i'm missing something important about the inherince

Comment: When you call `-searcht:` and it works, where is that `customers` instance defined? How do you get to it?

Comment: searht is defined in customers. when i called it from customers it works perfectly. then i made a subclass of nssearchfield that import customers.h and in the keyup event i wanted to call the method but it can't reach the variables defined in customers

Comment: When it is called and it works, is there code somewhere like your line `customers* c= [[customers alloc] init];`? If not, where is the instance of `customers` created? That seems to be the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your IBOutlet connections are broken. When you create an instance of `customers` in the `-keyDown` event, none of your outlets are connected. That's why it's broken. This is not a problem with inheritance, so much as object-oriented design. You probably need to rethink how your functions talk to each other.

To prove whether this is the case (I'm sorry, but I'm having some trouble reading your code), add a log statement in your `-searcht:` function to see if it exists:

```
NSLog(@"name1field: %@", name1);
```

I'm guessing that you'll see something like: `name1field: (null)`

**Updated with suggested solution**

If you have IBOutlets there (which strikes me as a questionable decision), that means it's instantiated in your nib. What you will probably want to do (assuming you don't drastically alter your code's structure) is create an outlet in your `NSSearchField` subclass, connect it to the `customers` object in your nib, and use that, instead of creating a new instance of `customers`.

This is a band-aid solution, though. You may want to read up on some of the [design patterns used in Cocoa code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html). That might give you some better ideas for how to structure your classes.

Comment: Another question . could i declare variables in a class and use methods in another class to access and assign values to this variables. then in my parent class use this variables to give a stringValue to my IBOutlets?

Comment: I don't think your problems have anything to do with inheritance. I think you need to read up on how NIBs and IBOutlets work. You can access IBOutlets from the class they're defined in, and any subclasses. They're just a specially-marked kind of variable. You need to get a reference to the correct instance at runtime, though - I think that's where you're having problems.